# It is well-known that hyperbolic space is delta-hyperbolic, but what is delta?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Recall that a space is $\delta$-hyperbolic if there is some number $\delta$ with the property that every point on an edge of a geodesic triangle lies within $\delta$ of another edge.  For example a tree is $0$-hyperbolic.  One of the basic facts about standard hyperbolic space is that it is $\delta$-hyperbolic for some $\delta$, and I am looking for the smallest delta which makes this true.

Full disclosure: I stole this question from Dima Burago, who brought it up as an example of of a useless problem about which he is nevertheless a little curious.  I haven't exactly burned the midnight oil, but I can't solve it.

Comment: This is a well-known elementary exercise mentioned in Bridson-Heafliger and other places. Incidentally, the optimal delta is not totally useless: it could be helpful when doing explicit computations in $H^n$. For example, a cool fact is that in $H^n$ any $r$-quasi-convex set lies in bounded Hausdorff distance from its convex hull, and I would like to know this distance as a function of $r$; I suspect the optimal delta will be part of the formula.

Comment: @Will -- the distance between the midpoints is not the desired delta.  Paul is asking for the slightly smaller distance from one midpoint to the other edges. 

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can use the isometry group of $H^n$ to reduce to the case of an ideal triangle in the upper half plane, with vertices at -1, 1, and infinity.  We want to find the distance between $i$ and the vertical geodesic with real part 1.  To find the shortest geodesic, we reflect $i$ in the vertical line, and take half the distance between $i$ and $i+2$.  The [distance formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincare_metric) yields $\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{|(i+2)-i|}{|(i+2) + i|} \right) = \tanh^{-1}(1/\sqrt2)$.  This is about 0.8813735.

Comment: You're quite right.  I should have considered more symmetric means.

Comment: There is a Mobius transformation turning your proof into my proof.  Of course, Mobius transformations have inverses... :)

Comment: since a geodesic triangle is always contained in a totally geodesic plane why can't we deduce immediately that the $\delta$-hyperbolicity constant of $\mathbb{H}^2$ is optimal, i.e. $\operatorname{log}(2)$?

Comment: ok i just realised that the difinition of hyperbolicity used here is not the $4$-points definition for which the constant is $\operatorname{log}(2)$, but can the same reasoning still apply? are there precise relations between the constants of the different definitions or are these equivalent only under upper and lower linear bounds?

Answer (score 12):

Consider the ideal triangle with vertices at infinity,
zero, and one.  Let $C$ be the semicircle perpendicular to the vertical line $[0, \infty]$ and
meeting $1/2 + i/2$ (ie the midpoint of the semicircle $[0,1]$).  So $C$ meets $[0,
\infty]$ at the point $i \cdot \sqrt{2}/2$.  Scale down by a factor of
$\sqrt{2}/2$ to get the point $1/\sqrt{2} + i/\sqrt{2}$.  Use a Mobius transformation to rotate
this by $\pi/2$ about $i$ to get $i(1+\sqrt{2})$.  Now integrate
$dy/y$ to get $\log(1 + \sqrt{2})$. This is approximately 0.88137358702.

Comment: Thanks, Sam. I started drawing pictures after Matthew seemed to get something different but didn't get very far. Just as well I did not finish the calculation.

Answer (score 4):

Let $T$ be a triangle in $\mathbb{H}^2$. Its area is $\pi - \alpha - \beta - \gamma$, where $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are the interior angles. You can find how slim this triangle is by considering an inscribed circle in $T$. The radius of this triangle, thus $\delta$, are bounded above by the area, so to find the $\delta$ that works for all triangles, you take the limit and consider an ideal triangle $T_\infty$. You can explicitly compute that the inscribed circle minimizing distance between the sides has length $4 \log \phi$, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio. (See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_triangle) and [here](http://392c.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/more-quasi-isometry-and-hyperbolic-metric-spaces/).)

Comment: If you make the ideal triangle in the disk model, the $4 \log \phi$ comes from connecting the midpoints. It's the minimum distance between the sides. 

Comment: Ahh, I see the confusion. I said radius instead of hyperbolic length. Edit forthcoming.

Comment: That second link explains the correct way forward - you want to inscribe a semicircle inside of the triangle, not a circle.  Doing the latter will give the in-radius instead of the slimness constant.  I don't know what the problem with Wikipedia is - it looks like they are computing the distance between midpoints, but is too large by a factor of two.

Comment: Well, that's what I get for not checking it...

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.math.umn.edu/~am/book/outercircles.pdf, p.14-15 for detailed treatment.