# Optimal $\delta$ for Gromov's $\delta$-hyperbolicity of the hyperbolic plane

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

What is the minimal $\delta$ such that the hyperbolic plane is $\delta$-hyperbolic, in the sense of the four point definition of Gromov?

**Four point definition of Gromov:** A metric space $(X, d)$ is $\delta$-hyperbolic if, for all $w, x, y, z \in X$,
$$ d(w, x) + d(y, z) \leq \text{max}\{d(x, y) + d(w, z), d(x, z) + d(w, y) \} +2\delta. $$

Empirically, the minimal value seems to be approximately $0.693$.

There is a [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23061/it-is-well-known-that-hyperbolic-space-is-delta-hyperbolic-but-what-is-delta), but this concerns the optimal $\delta$ in the $\delta$-slim definition.  While this implies a bound on the $\delta$ of the four point definition, it hasn't yet helped me to derive the minimal value.

Any help (or a reference) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take 4 points far apart and compute the difference.

Comment: If you take 4 points at infinity, their only invariant is the cross ratio. So it should be possible to compute $\delta$ as a function of the cross ratio and find its minimum.

Comment: @ThiKu: You do not want any of the four distances to be $\infty$.

Comment: @dodd: ThiKu certainly meant to consider the limit as point go to infinity of the difference $d(w,z)+d(y,z)-\max\{d(x,y)+d(w,z),d(x,z)+d(w,y)\}$.

Comment: For this, you could get points to go to infinity one at a time, using Buseman functions (which are limits of différence between distance functions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, the hyperbolic plane is $\log(2)$-hyperbolic (with the 4-point definition of hyperbolicity) and this is the optimal constant. The result is nontrivial and first appeared as Corollary 5.4 in

*Nica, Bogdan; Špakula, Ján*, [**Strong hyperbolicity**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4171/GGD/372), Groups Geom. Dyn. 10, No. 3, 951-964 (2016). [ZBL1368.20057](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1368.20057).

Answer (score 7):

The answer is $\delta = \ln(2) \approx 0.693147181$.

> Claim: The correct placement of the four points at infinity is at the
> corners of an ideal square.

With the claim in hand, we can compute $\delta$ in the upper half plane model.  We place the points at $0, 1, \infty, -1$.  We place identical horocircles at each of these points.  These are cyclically tangent, and all have the same minimal distance $\delta/2$ from the point $i$.  The points of tangency are cyclically permuted by the order four rotation about $i$.  If we take boundary of the horosphere about $\infty$ to be the line $y = H$ then we discover that the order four element (fixing $i$) sends $1 + iH$ to $-1 + 2i/H = -1 + iH$.  Thus $H = \sqrt{2}$.  So $\delta$ is twice the distance from $i$ to $i\sqrt{2}$ and we are done.

The proof of the claim appears to be difficult.  We have to prove that, given four material points, we can increase $\delta$ by first moving them "outward" to lie on a circle (tricky), then to lie symmetrically on the circle (medium), and then increase the radius of the circle to infinity (easy).